# Flask RESTful - query SQLalchemy return two lists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am beginner on python, I am currently working on an api grouping restaurants.

The trouble being that when I join two tables restaurants and address, the query SQLAlchemy sends me 2 lists however I would like to merge his lists

I learned about : https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many

my two class : Restaurants and Adresse

```
restaurant_adresse_association = db.Table(
   'restaurant_adresse',
    db.Column('restaurant_id', db.Integer, ForeignKey('restaurants.id')),
    db.Column('adresse_id', db.Integer, ForeignKey('adresse.id'))
)

 class Restaurants(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'restaurants'
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   nom = db.Column(db.String(255))
   description = db.Column(db.String(255))
   creation = db.Column(db.DateTime)
   heure_ouverture = db.Column(db.DateTime)
   heure_fermeture = db.Column(db.DateTime)
   url_photo = db.Column(db.String(255))
   rang = db.Column(db.Integer)
   adresse = db.relationship('Adresse',secondary=restaurant_adresse_association)


 class Adresse(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'adresse'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ville = db.Column(db.String(255))
    code_postal = db.Column(db.String(255))
    rue = db.Column(db.String(255))
    restaurant = db.relationship('Restaurants', secondary=restaurant_adresse_association)
    longitude = db.Column(db.Float)
    latitude = db.Column(db.Float)
```

Restaurant.py:

```
champs_restaurant = {
'id': fields.Integer(attribute='id'),
'name': fields.String(attribute='nom'),
'city': fields.String(attribute='ville'),
'address': fields.String(attribute='rue'),
'postal code': fields.String(attribute='code_postal'),
'description': fields.String,
'opening time': fields.String(attribute='heure_ouverture'),
'closing time': fields.String(attribute='heure_fermeture'),
'picture': fields.String(attribute='url_photo'),
'rank': fields.Integer(attribute='rang')
 }

@marshal_with(champs_restaurant)
def get(self):
    resto = session.query(Restaurants, Adresse).join(Adresse, Restaurants.adresse).all()
    return resto, 201
```

Result :

```
[
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hugiz",
        "city": null,
        "address": null,
        "postal code": null,
        "description": "Fastfood",
        "opening time": "9:00",
        "closing time": "18:00",
        "picture": null,
        "rank": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": null,
        "city": "Paris",
        "address": "1-3 Rue de Savies",
        "postal code": "75020",
        "description": null,
        "opening time": null,
        "closing time": null,
        "picture": null,
        "rank": 0
    }
],
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "estampille",
        "city": null,
        "address": null,
        "postal code": null,
        "description": "Pizza",
        "opening time": "9:00",
        "closing time": "18:00",
        "picture": null,
        "rank": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": null,
        "city": "Rouen",
        "address": "1 Rue Thomas Becket",
        "postal code": "76130",
        "description": null,
        "opening time": null,
        "closing time": null,
        "picture": null,
        "rank": 0
    }
]
```

test:

```
@marshal_with(champs_restaurant)
def get(self):
    resto = session.query(Restaurants).join(Adresse).all()
    return resto, 201
```

result :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.  Tried joining to <class 'source.Restaurant.modèle.modele_restaurant.Adresse'>, but got: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'restaurants' and 'adresse'.
```

Test:

```
@marshal_with(champs_restaurant)
def get(self):
    resto = session.query(Restaurants).join(Adresse, Restaurants.adresse).all()
    return resto, 201
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hugiz",
        "city": null,
        "address": null,
        "postal code": null,
        "description": "Fastfood",
        "opening time": "9:00",
        "closing time": "18:00",
        "picture": null,
        "rank": 4
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "estampille",
        "city": null,
        "address": null,
        "postal code": null,
        "description": "Pizza",
        "opening time": "9:00",
        "closing time": "18:00",
        "picture": null,
        "rank": 4
    }
]
```

expected result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hugiz",
        "city": "Paris",
        "address": "1-3 Rue de Savies",
        "postal code": "75020",
        "description": "Fastfood",
        "opening time": "9:00",
        "closing time": "18:00",
        "picture": null,
        "rank": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "estampille",
        "city": "Rouen",
        "address": "1 Rue Thomas Becket",
        "postal code": "76130",
        "description": "Pizza",
        "opening time": "9:00",
        "closing time": "18:00",
        "picture": null,
        "rank": 4
    }
]
```

Comment: They are lists not tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying two tables with:

```
session.query(Restaurants, Adresse)
```

This is basically equivalent to a SQL statement like

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants, adresse;
```

which creates an [implicit cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) between the tables, which is probably not what you want.  Without seeing `champs_restaurant` it's hard to say exactly what's happening after that, but it seems it's then trying to cram results containing columns from both tables into a JSON format intended for the combined results.

Part of the point of configuring relationships in SQLAlchemy ORMs is you can query on a table and SQLAlchemy will generally build the correct join for you assuming the foreign key relations are sane, so it should be sufficient, if you want to list all restaurants, to do:

```
session.query(Restaurants).all()
```

Here you'll get a list of `Restaurants` instances with the their `.adresse` attribute filled with a list of associated (`Adresse` instances) via the association table you configured.  It should use the associate table provided by the `secondary=` argument to `relation` to work out the correct join relations.  If for some reason that still doesn't work we'll have to take a closer look but generally that's the idea.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for answering me, I am still learning and all your advice is good to take

Comment: No, I must surely have errors with my relationship, I've updated my question with your suggestions

Comment: do you think it's possible that "Marshal_with" that's a problem?

Comment: I updated my answer: In fact you shouldn't need the explicit `.join(...)` at all.  Just `session.query(Restaurants)` should suffice.  The reason for the error you got is because `Query.join(...)` is simplistic in that it does not automatically take into account the many-to-many relationship, and is instead looking for a column on one table or the other containing a foreign key to the other table (which doesn't exist in this case because the relationship is through the association table).